# How to make my images sizes fix but not compromising/deforming its looks?

Tags: html, css

I'm having problem using images on my project. I want it to look just like the first two images. When I tried to fix the height of the images via CSS, it becomes ugly. Is there a way that it will just resize by itself without overlapping like what happened on the third image?

CSS :

```
.product-image-wrapper{
 border:1px solid #F7F7F5;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-bottom:30px;
 }

.single-products {
 position: relative;
 }

.new, .sale {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 }

.productinfo h2{
 color: #FE980F;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 24px;
 font-weight: 700;
 }
.product-overlay h2{
 color: #fff;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 24px;
 font-weight: 700;
 }


.productinfo p{
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: 400;
 color: #696763;
 }

.productinfo img{
 width: 100%;
 }

.productinfo{
position:relative;
}

.product-overlay {
 background:#FE980F;
 top: 0;
 display: none;
 height: 0;
 position: absolute;
 transition: height 500ms ease 0s;
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
 opacity:;
 }

.single-products:hover .product-overlay {
display:block;
height:100%;
}


.product-overlay .overlay-content {
bottom: 0;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
}

.product-overlay .add-to-cart {
background:#fff;
border: 0 none;
border-radius: 0;
color: #FE980F;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.product-overlay .add-to-cart:hover {
background:#fff;
color: #FE980F;
}


.product-overlay p{
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 400;
color: #fff;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jamerza/kdfxgt25/)

> What my actual page look like:

[image]

Comment: please include the relevant html in the question itself

Comment: If you specify only fixed width than height will be automatic.

Comment: please please please reduce this sample into a minimal demo. Currently, trawling through code to see the problem is difficult/annoying

Answer (score 0):

Cropping the image to the right size is probably your best bet.  Other alternatives would be creating a div that wraps around the third image, and giving that div exact dimensions and setting `overflow:hidden`.  That will basically crop the image.  Honestly I think you are better off cropping the image yourself though, because then its easier to control what shows up.  You'll have to deal with cropping in some way if you want to avoid stretching.